# Ubuntu on a Gigatbye Brix Pro?

Tags: system-installation

are there any one in here that has tried to install ubuntu on a Gigabyte Brix Pro? I think it is the same as the steam box that comes later this year

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a Gigabyte Brix Pro ([GB-BXi7-4770R](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4888#ov)) with G.Skill 16 GB DDR3-1866 Kit (F3-1866C10D-16GRSL, Ripjaws) and a Mushkin Atlas Deluxe (MKNSSDAT240GB-DX) 240GB SSD currently running Ubuntu 14.04 (dualboot with Arch Linux).

[image: brixpro]

With 14.04 everything works out-of-the box, older Ubuntu versions encountered (disk)problems during installation (file corruption).

My Brix Pro has an Intel Iris Pro 5200 GPU, Gigabyte has also announced an Brix Gaming which is AMD-based ([GB-BXA8G-8890](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4930#ov)).

The Brix-based Steambox will, IMHO, most-likely have a Nvidia GPU.

Comment: Does Wi-Fi work too?

Comment: Yes, Wifi works fine.